# Jooq XML Database generation

Tags: jooq, cratedb, jooq-codegen-maven

I am manually defining a Database XML schema to use the Jooq capabilities to generate the corresponding code from the definition.
I am using Gradle to generate the code with Jooq:

```json
jooq {
    version = '3.13.5'
    edition = nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition.OSS
    configurations {
        crate {  
            generationTool {
                logging = org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging.INFO
                generator {
                    database {
                        name = 'org.jooq.meta.xml.XMLDatabase'
                        properties {
                            property {
                                key = 'dialect'
                                value = 'POSTGRES'
                            }
                            property {
                                key = 'xmlFile'
                                value = 'src/main/resources/crate_information_schema.xml'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    target {
                        packageName = 'it.fox.crate'
                        directory = 'src/generated/crate'
                    }
                    strategy.name = "it.fox.generator.CrateGenerationStrategy"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the XML file `crate_information_schema.xml` I am referencing:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<information_schema xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-meta-3.14.0.xsd">
    <schemata>
        <schema>
            <catalog_name></catalog_name>
            <schema_name>doc</schema_name>
            <comment></comment>
        </schema>
    </schemata>
    <tables>
        <table>
            <table_catalog></table_catalog>
            <table_schema>doc</table_schema>
            <table_name>events</table_name>
            <table_type>BASE TABLE</table_type>
            <comment></comment>
        </table>
    </tables>
    <columns>
        <column>
            <table_catalog></table_catalog>
            <table_schema>doc</table_schema>
            <table_name>events</table_name>
            <column_name>data_block['angularPositionArray']</column_name>
            <data_type>real_array</data_type>
            <character_maximum_length>0</character_maximum_length>
            <numeric_precision>19</numeric_precision>
            <numeric_scale>0</numeric_scale>
            <ordinal_position>1</ordinal_position>
            <is_nullable>false</is_nullable>
            <comment>angularPositionArray</comment>
        </column>
        <column>
            <table_catalog></table_catalog>
            <table_schema>doc</table_schema>
            <table_name>events</table_name>
            <column_name>data_block['eventId']</column_name>
            <data_type>bigint(20)</data_type>
            <character_maximum_length>0</character_maximum_length>
            <numeric_precision>19</numeric_precision>
            <numeric_scale>0</numeric_scale>
            <ordinal_position>1</ordinal_position>
            <is_nullable>false</is_nullable>
            <comment>eventId</comment>
        </column>
    </columns>
</information_schema>
```

The code generated is not good, because it indicate the Data Type used is unknown:

```java
 /**
     * @deprecated Unknown data type. Please define an explicit {@link org.jooq.Binding} to specify how this type should be handled. Deprecation can be turned off using {@literal <deprecationOnUnknownTypes/>} in your code generator configuration.
     */
    @java.lang.Deprecated
    public final TableField<EventsRecord, Object> angularPositionArray = createField(DSL.name("data_block['angularPositionArray']"), org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDefaultDataType("\"real_array\"").nullable(false), this, "angularPositionArray");
```

I have a couple of questions:

- which is the correct data type for Real Array?
- where is the list of supported data type with the keys to use in the XML?

N.B. CrateDB is an unsupported DataBase but Jooq could talk to the DB using the Postgres driver, the only problem is to create manually the schema.

Answer (score 1):

> which is the correct data type for Real Array?

Use `<data_type>REAL ARRAY</data_type>` (with a whitespace, and upper case, see comments and issue [#12611](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12611))

> where is the list of supported data type with the keys to use in the XML?

It's the same as for any other code generation data source: All the types in [`SQLDataType`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/SQLDataType.html) are supported. The convention around array types is currently undocumented, but any of HSQLDB's or PostgreSQL's notations should work. The feature request to formally support array types as user defined types via standard SQL `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ELEMENT_TYPES` is here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8090

> N.B. CrateDB is an unsupported DataBase but Jooq could talk to the DB using the Postgres driver, the only problem is to create manually the schema.

You can obviously use the `XMLDatabase` for this. I'm guessing you cannot use the `JDBCDatabase`, because the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is too different, and the `PG_CATALOG` schema doesn't exist? However, you could easily implement your own `org.jooq.meta.Database`, too, if that makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried `<data_type>real array</data_type>` but I still have: 

`
    @Deprecated
    public final TableField<EventsRecord, Object> DATA_BLOCK_5b_27ANGULARPOSITIONARRAY_27_5d = createField(DSL.name("data_block['angularPositionArray']"), org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDefaultDataType("\"real array\"").nullable(false), this, "angularPositionArray");
`

and:

`
20:25:30 INFO Reading from: src/main/resources/crate_information_schema.xml [*]
20:25:30 INFO ARRAYs fetched           : 0 (0 included, 0 excluded)
`

Do you know why ?
Regards

Comment: While investigating, I've found a bug related to case sensitivity: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12611. It works for me with `<data_type>REAL ARRAY</data_type>`. It doesn't look like the same issue, though who knows. Perhaps, report a bug with a fully self contained reproducer here? https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose. There's a template to create such reproducers here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve

Comment: Still no success. I have created a real Postgres DB with a `phone_numbers real[]` column and used `org.jooq.codegen.XMLGenerator` to reverse the XML. The xml generator generate a `<data_type>ARRAY</data_type>` column specification not a `REAL ARRAY` one. The opposite with ARRAY create a `Object[]` and `REAL ARRAY` doesn't work. I am using 3.15.4 version. Do I have to wait the next one ?

Comment: Please report a bug with details to reproduce. I don't have the full picture from your question. Keeping in mind that the issue to *formally* support array types in this XML format is not yet implemented: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8090, and that you're using an unsupported dialect, meaning that with such edge cases (such as array types), the dialect might get in the way, as the XML format also tries to mimick the output produced by e.g. `PostgresDatabase` or `H2Database` for the rest of the code generator to work.

Comment: The information schema for CrateDB should be similar, although not identical. Also we do have large parts of the PG_CATALOG schema implemented in CrateDB. I would also be happy to assist to get CrateDB fully compatible :)

Comment: @proddata: We're open to sponsored projects

Comment: Having CrateDB integrated with jooq will be wonderful !

Comment: @StefanoBossi: You can upvote here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12629. But sponsoring will produce faster results :)